# How to provide force update to iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store, iosdeployment

I want to upload a new version of iOS application to iTunes with re-branding logo and design So I want to force users to update it.

Can anybody please guide me how can I force the user to update my new app in store? Is there any cause can happens if I forced user? and Is there any code change required to force update or any iTunes setting required during build upload?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no default method available in iTunes Connect to achieve this functionality. But I've done this in one of my application.

In my application, when each time it opens/becomes active I call a web-service and pass the current app version to it. This service returns a result, something similar to:

```
{
   "version" : 3.7,
   "shouldUpdate" : true,
   "message" : "Security Improvements......."
}
```

When I get result like this, I check whether the `shouldUpdate` flag is true or not. If it's true I'll show an alert with the server message retrieved above. This alert have only one button and clicking on it, I open the AppStore page of my application (So there is no way user can skip this update).

In my case the code was already there and the force update will work just fine. But in your case, the current app doesn't have any such implementation, so for you it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks @Midhun for info but, in my case, I didn't write similar code in my previous version of app and now I want to give and forced update to user in new version of app.